# How to integrate UIPATH with SVN?

Tags: svn, uipath

I am currently working in RPA tool UIPATH. I now have to integrate UIPATH with SVN. I don`t have an idea to proceed. Please help me on how to integrate UIPATH with SVN?

Comment: What kind of integration are you looking for? "Integration" could mean practically anything. That's why the question is not clear.

Comment: I meant that from UIPATH itself .. we could track our changes into SVN repo

Comment: There should be option to commit our codes into SVN from UIPATH

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in two ways. But for both, you should have a repository created in SVN server and you should have required permissions for the repo URL.

1. Using TortoiseSVN client:

   - Download the client installer and install it in your machine.
   - Go to the folder where your source code is there, right click > SVN Checkout.
   - Enter URL of repository and make sure of the Checkout directory. Click OK.
   - A prompt to enter User Name and Password will be displayed. Enter valid details and click OK.
   - The source code will be bonded to your repository.
   - Now open UI Path studio and open the project that you added into repository.
   - Open Projects Tab. You could see an indication that project is already connected to SVN.
     [Connected to Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyNdj.png)
2. Directly Connecting from UI Path Studio:

   - Open UI Path studio and open the project that you want to connect to repository.
   - Open Projects Tab. On the action bar, there will be an icon to connect to source control.[Connect To Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdXXk.png)
   - Click on the icon, Select SVN and click "Connect to Project".
   - A prompt to enter Repository URL will be popped out. Enter repository URL and your credentials.
   - On clicking OK, the project will be added to your repository and In projects tab, you could see an indication to show project is connected to SVN.